# Modifying / Installing stock firmware on ISP Branded WRE2205

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, linux, firmware

Our ISP, MWeb, gave us a free router and Wifi extender (WRE2205v2) as part of a new promotion. Neither of them really work at all (the extender works for about a minute then fails for no apparent reason). Acording to reviews, it should be a decent repeater, but it seems Mweb has completely screwed up the firmware.

[This blog post](http://simonfredsted.com/996) shows how to get very basic root access (it's running embedded Linux) on the device (the security is... bad). So far I've worked out it's a MIPS device (running `file` on an executable gives `ELF 32-bit MSB  executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV)` and the file system is squash-fs, so read only. I can also copy files to/from the device using tftp.

I also know that both the branded firmware and the stock firmware use a binary called fw_upgrade to flash a new firmware. I tried decompiling them using http://decompiler.fit.vutbr.cz/decompilation/ but I haven't had much luck there. The branded one has a bit more code which I assume checks something about the new firmware and prevents the stock firmware from being flashed. Finally I tried copying the stock fw_upgrade to the device and running it but it fails without an error message.

What else can I do to get the stock firmware running?

Comment: Branded fw_upgrade: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8ibvv7w39g8ozy/fw_upgrade_isp?dl=0
Stock: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zp21r8ijm2dpdph/fw_upgrade?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got it working. Turns out I didn't need to modify the binary. After extracting the squash-fs file system from the update file, I managed to copy fw_update to the device using tftp. Running that binary (`/etc/fw_update upg fw.bin`) instead of the ISP one worked and flashed the stock firmware. The binary needs to be copied to /etc or /var because the rest is read-only.

Answer (score 3):

A cursory examination of the two files suggests that the main difference in upgrade paths between the two binaries is that the branded one calls a function named `chkfwid`. If I'm reading the code correctly, it searches the first `0x800` bytes for the four ASCII bytes `1213`; if found, the function succeeds, else it fails and the upgrade is terminated.

Comment: How did you decompile them? Is it possible to remove this check from it?

Comment: I disassembled them with IDA. It would be simple to remove the check, but there may be other things that need to be changed too, as I did not perform an in depth analysis of the two binaries.

Comment: Thanks, actually it turns out it wasn't necessary to modify the binary